# How to stage files with JGit in a bare repository?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I read the [question and answer for staging files in a non-bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734760/jgit-how-to-add-all-files-to-staging-area). However, I am working with a bare repository and I would like to stage files.

I tried using the [test for DirCacheBuilder](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/dircache/DirCacheBuilderTest.java), but the code `Repository.lockDirCache()` or `Repository.readDirCache()` fails because this is a bare repository.

> org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.getIndexFile(Repository.java:993)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.read(DirCache.java:166)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.readDirCache(Repository.java:1017)

So, how could I stage files in a bare repository using JGit? is this even possible?

Comment: If you ultimately want to commit to a bare repository (and this is really what you want do) this question might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320996/jgit-bare-commit-tree-construction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how could I stage files in a bare repository using JGit?

You wouldn't, as the error states:

```
Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
```

No index, means no staging.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "stage" files, but you can still add new file and commits to a bare repository.  [Here's a good snippet](https://gist.github.com/porcelli/3882505).